# No table found in SugarRecord using Retrofit

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm, sugarrecord

I am using Retrofit to access data and for storing I am using SugarRecord.I am new to SugarRecord Orm.

**Manifest:**

```
meta-data
        android:name="DATABASE"
        android:value="sugar_example.db"
meta-data
        android:name="VERSION"
        android:value="3"
meta-data
        android:name="QUERY_LOG"
        android:value="false"
meta-data
        android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
        android:value="com.example.abhishek.ModelClass"
```

**ClsDocument:**

```
public class ClsDocument {
@SerializedName("SUCCESS")
@Expose
private String sUCCESS;
@SerializedName("DATA")
@Expose
private List<ClsDocumentList> dATA = null;
}
```

**Setter and getter I had not posted**
Here is ClsDocument List which is in ArrayFormat
**ClsDocumentList:**

```
public class ClsDocumentList extends SugarRecord {
@SerializedName("SCHEME_ID")
private String sCHEMEID;
@SerializedName("DOCUMENT_TYPE")
private String dOCUMENTTYPE;
}
```

**Initialise DataBase in onCreate:**

```
SugarContext.init(getApplicationContext());
```

Here is my DemoCode:

```
private void demoRetrofit() {
    InterfaceDocument interfaceDocument = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceDocument.class);
    Call<ClsDocument> call = interfaceDocument.CLS_DOCUMENT_CALL();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ClsDocument>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ClsDocument> call, Response<ClsDocument> response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.body().getSUCCESS() );

            String success=response.body().getSUCCESS();
            if(success.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                for (ClsDocumentList objList:response.body().getDATA()) {
                    objList.save();//To save in SugarRecord
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ClsDocument> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Here is a Log:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: CLS_DOCUMENT_LIST (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO CLS_DOCUMENT_LIST(ID,S_CHEMEID,D_OCUMENTNAME,D_OCUMENTTYPE,S_ELECTTYPE,D_OCUMENTMODULE,M_ANDATORY) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

Grateful for your guidence.

Comment: Please add the code for `ClsDocument.java` file model here

Comment: Edited Chintak Patel...Do tell me what is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your model class file `ClsDocumentList` as coded below.

```
public class ClsDocumentList extends SugarRecord<ClsDocumentList> {
    @SerializedName("SCHEME_ID")
    private String sCHEMEID;

    @SerializedName("DOCUMENT_TYPE")
    private String dOCUMENTTYPE;
}
```

Replace your `SugarRecord` to `SugarRecord<ClsDocumentList>` which will map this class to `SugarRecord Table`.

For more, refer this [link](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/creation.html) for creating Table using SugarRecord.

Comment: Still Error is coming...no such table: CLS_DOCUMENT_LIST

Comment: Are you having same error now or other error is showing to you ?

Comment: Please put this code in `onCreate()`, `SugarDb db = new SugarDb(this);
    db.onCreate(db.getDB());`

Comment: Still not resolved.......Same error I am not getting.Can you give me one demo example link.

Comment: @AbhishekBardolia, Please change version as 1 in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Put this code `<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="1" />`